# TypeError: Cannot convert value <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=8> to a TensorFlow DType

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, nlp

Can anyone help me solving this error:

> TypeError: Cannot convert value <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=8> to a TensorFlow DType.

While I am coding transformers from scratch, i got the msg so I share with you my code:

```
class Transformer (tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, vocab_size_encoder, vocab_size_decoder, d_model, n_layers,units, n_head, dropout_rate, name="Transformer"):
    super(Transformer, self).__init__(name=name)
    self.encoder = Encoder(n_layers, units, n_head, dropout_rate, vocab_size_encoder, d_model)
    self.decoder = Encoder(n_layers, units, n_head, dropout_rate, vocab_size_decoder, d_model)
    self.dense_layer = layers.Dense(vocab_size_decoder) 

  def create_padding_mask(self, sequence):
    mask = tf.cast(tf.math.equal(sequence, 0), tf.float32)
    return mask[:, tf.newaxis, tf.newaxis, :]

  def create_look_ahead_mask(self, sequence):
    sequence_length = tf.shape(sequence)[1]
    mask = 1 - tf.linalg.band_part(tf.ones(sequence_length,sequence_length),-1,0)
    return mask 
  
  def call(self, encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs, training):
    encoder_mask = self.create_padding_mask(encoder_inputs)
    decoder_mask1 = self.create_padding_mask(decoder_inputs)
    decoder_mask2 = tf.maximum(
        self.create_padding_mask(decoder_inputs),
        self.create_look_ahead_mask(decoder_inputs))
    encoder_outputs = self.encoder(encoder_inputs,
                                   encoder_mask, 
                                   training)
    decoder_outputs = self.decoder(decoder_inputs,encoder_outputs,decoder_mask2, decoder_mask1, training)
    final_outputs  = self.dense_layer(decoder_outputs)

    return final_outputs
```

And this simple example is for testing the code:

```
encoder_inputs= tf.constant([[1,5,6,4,3,9,5,2,8],
                           [1,8,7,3,4,5,6,7,2]])
decoder_inputs= tf.constant([[1,4,7,3,5,7,2,8,1],
                           [1,8,2,3,5,6,3,4,2]])

transformer_test = Transformer(vocab_size_encoder=10, 
                               vocab_size_decoder=10, 
                               d_model=9,
                               n_layers=6,
                               units=50,
                               n_head=4, 
                               dropout_rate=0.01)

y = transformer_test(encoder_inputs,
                     decoder_inputs[:,:-1])
```

This is just for the sake of testing.
Otherwise, for more about the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-98be24bcdd5c> in <module>()
      1 y = transformer_test(encoder_inputs,
----> 2                      decoder_inputs[:,:-1])

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py in as_dtype(type_value)
    646 
    647   raise TypeError("Cannot convert value %r to a TensorFlow DType." %
--> 648                   (type_value,))

TypeError: Cannot convert value <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=8> to a TensorFlow DType.
```

[image: Error]

Comment: The image actually does not "clarify everything" -- the entire middle of the error trace is missing. Please post the full error traceback, as part of your question, not as an image.

Comment: @xdurch0 I hope it is clear now, I edited the qst,

Comment: Have you tried to convert it to float32?  For example: `tf.constant([[1,4,7,3,5,7,2,8,1],
                           [1,8,2,3,5,6,3,4,2]],dtype=tf.float32)`

Comment: @Kaveh Yes, I did and I got the same error msg ..

Comment: No, that is not the full error message. There is "5 frames" in there. It seems that your IDE is collapsing the message and only showing the beginning/end. We need the _full_ trace.

Comment: @xdurch0 I got it, and I solved the issue .. 

Inside the create_look_ahead_mask function, instead of this 
```    mask = 1 - tf.linalg.band_part(tf.ones(sequence_length,sequence_length),-1,0)
```
I should write this 

```     mask = 1 - tf.linalg.band_part(tf.ones((sequence_length,sequence_length)),-1,0)
``` 
So that i got a tensor .. 
Thank you Guys ..

Comment: And about the 5 frames error msg, I am working on GoogleColab and just by clicking the 5 frames, it displays the entire msg .. I am still newbie in Colab..

Answer (score 0):

y = transformer_test(encoder_inputs,
decoder_inputs[:,:-1])

I don't know why used comma in decoder_inputs might be type error.

y = transformer_test(encoder_inputs,
decoder_inputs[::-1]) use this

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the problem is already solved please check the comments above. Otherwise, the decoder is a sample example to see that it runs, and the "," means that we are gonna shift by one, so that it does not have the end of the sentence token, because we wanted to learn to predict the end of the sentence...